# Does autocommit in postgresql mean you cannot have transaction blocks?

Tags: sql, postgresql

if autocommit is on, which is default, postgresql treats each statement as a transaction.

so if i have an explicit transaction block with `start transaction` and `commit`, does that mean that block is not executed atomically and cannot be rolled back? (since each statement inside the block would be a transaction in itself due to autocommit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the opposite.

With autocommit turned on, using `start transaction` is the only way to combine multiple statements into a single transaction.

In fact, Postgres always uses autocommit on the server, **unless** the client uses `start transaction` (or `begin transaction`). When you turn off auto-commit the client will simply send those statements for you automatically.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html)

> BEGIN initiates a transaction block, that is, all statements after a BEGIN command will be executed in a single transaction until an explicit COMMIT or ROLLBACK is given. **By default (without BEGIN)**, PostgreSQL executes transactions in “autocommit” mode

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

`BEGIN` is the same as `START TRANSACTION`

Comment: ["By default, embedded SQL programs are not in autocommit mode"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html)

Comment: @Andomar: well, that's ECPG - which is just another "client" (similar to JDBC's `Connection.setAutocommit()`. The **SQL** statement `set autocommit` has been removed years ago.

Comment: Ah right, [psql defaults to autocommit off](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-psql.html) It says "The autocommit-on mode is PostgreSQL's traditional behavior" so looks like you're right about the default

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am confused. i thought `autocommit` was a client side setting, not a server side one. also what do you mean by `When you turn off auto-commit the client will simply send those statements for you automatically`. doesnt turning it off mean you have to explicity send those statments?

Comment: @pdeva: The Postgres sever defaults to on, but any client (like `psql`, or a library like Python's `psycopg2` or an ODBC driver through C#) can override that default.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but I assume what the client documentation says about "traditional behavior" is the server default

Comment: Yes it **is** a client side setting. If e.g. you turn it off in `psql`, then `psql` will automatically send a `begin` when you run a statement an no transaction was started. Same with the JDBC driver.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if jdbc automatically sends `begin/commit` with autocommit off, how is it any different from the user perspective to have it on or off?

Comment: Interesting: [The *server*
and its configuration files have no concept of autocommit, although
connectors and applications sometimes do.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACjxUsMwBh_vrE5bmpY%2BCqWgNnd4B3ewW0o-n%2BoVG3bi1FnSjg%40mail.gmail.com)

Comment: That quote from the mailing list is exactly what  I mean. And yes, from a user perspective there is no real difference

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name seems jdbc still requires sending `commit` manually when [autocommit is off](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit)

Comment: @pdeva: yes of course. That's the whole purpose of turning it off: to manually control the moment when commit or rollback is sent to the server to end the transaction started with `begin` - it's exactly the same thing as manually writing `begin; ....; commit;` - how else should the database know when to end the transaction?

Answer (score 3):

Autocommit only affects statements outside of a transaciton. When you do your own `start transaction` and `commit`, autocommit has no effect.

When a statement is run outside a transaction, autocommit

- ON means that means it is committed when it finishes
- OFF means that a new transaction is implicitly started, and an explicit `commit` is required to commit the statement

Comment: "*a new transaction is implicitly started*" should read: "*a new transaction is (implicitly) started by the client*"