WARNING: there is no transaction in process
I kind of ran into something interesting. I've executed a SQL script using pgAdmin as GUI. With both autocommit on and off respectably.
Executed script contains these statements as follows:
begin;
insert into test values (5);
rollback;
insert into test values (6);
rollback;
insert into test values (7);
commit;

I get this as result with both executions.
WARNING: there is no transaction in process 
WARNING: there is no transaction in process 
COMMIT
Obviously both warnings are contributed by the second rollback and the last commit. But why is there no difference in between those two executions although auto commit value is different when executing these scripts?
I've looked up for any explanation for this, but couldn't find anything useful for this kind of behavior.
What's the explanation for this?

I didn't read the question properly, it's about he behaviour of autocommit in pgadmin, and not why those warnings appear. I deleted my answer because I found a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57456218/4989143

Note that (with autocommit on, as is default) the second and third INSERT are committed immediately, since no explicit transaction is open any more. pgAdmin has no particular influence on this, so I removed that tag.

begin starts a transaction and both rollback and commit end the transaction. Because of this, the second rollback and the final commit are giving a warning that there is not an open transaction.
I think what you want is rollback to savepoint:
begin;
savepoint foo;
insert into test values (5);
rollback to savepoint foo;
insert into test values (6);
rollback to savepoint foo;
insert into test values (7);
commit;

This will undo all the work done after the savepoint but leave the transaction open.
